# Compiling a C/C++ project that uses external libraries using the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm completely new to Java and Android dev but I'm trying to port a C/C++ project to an android phone just to do some testing. Here are some details. The project depends on the Openssl, GMP, and NTL libraries. I downloaded copies and put everything inside a the `jni/` folder. So now the folder structure looks like this:

```
    jni/
       Android.mk
       gmp/
           Android.mk
           ...
       ntl/
           Android.mk
           ...
       openssl/
           Android.mk
           ...
       myproject/
           Android.mk
           ...
```

Every one of the subfolders that has `.cpp, c.` files has an Android.mk file. Now, my question is: very broadly, how should I go about structuring the contents of the Android.mk files? I was able to follow instructions online and compile Openssl (I produced all the .so files inside of it). How will the top-level Android.mk use these? Or does it now?

Answer (score 0):

When we run `ndk-build` in the top directory of your project (the parent of the jni directory in your picture), we essentially run [gnu make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Top) and **include** `jni/Android.mk`.

In your case, this top `jni/Android.mk` should only include all child .mk files:

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

The *main* file is `jni/myproject/Android.mk`, which refers to the binaries produced by others, like

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += openssl
```

and so on. Note that the names are not the names of library files, but of the `LOCAL_MODULE`'s that build them.

Often, it is easier to use static libraries. For example, you need to load all shared libraries from Java yourself, in the correct dependencies order.

---

***main*** is an informal word here. I just want to say that this is the make file that causes its siblings to do their work, and do it in expected order. It does that because it refers to the binaries produced by the other make files, by specifying `LOCAL_SHARD_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`.

It is important to understand that it is not enough to include all the make files in `jni/Android.mk` to cause them all do their work, and do it in expected order. I want to emphasize that the `jni/Android.mk` file is a *service* file, not the *main*, even though it sits on top of the directory hierarchy.

Comment: how do you make jni/myproject/Android.mk to be the main file? Also, how do you include the .mk files inside jni/Android.mk? And finally, which file should be called when I run ndk-build (i.e. inside which directory should I be)?